# PHP Warning: Module 'memcached' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, cpanel

I am using cPanel for Laravel project. And also quickbook too. But I got the error "**PHP Warning:  Module 'memcached' already loaded in Unknown on line 0**" when run the command `php artisan quickbooks:run`. As in other answers I check the php.ini file with WHM to comment that line but there is no such line. But in terminal when I run `php --ini` the output is:

```
[usesrs@CentOS etc]$ php --ini
PHP Warning:  Module 'memcached' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/10-opcache.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-bcmath.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-bz2.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-calendar.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-ctype.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-curl.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-dba.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-dom.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-enchant.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-exif.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-fileinfo.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-ftp.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-gd.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-gettext.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-gmp.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-iconv.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-imap.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-intl.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-json.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-ldap.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-mbstring.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-mcrypt.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-mysqlnd.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-odbc.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-pdo.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-phar.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-posix.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-pspell.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-shmop.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-simplexml.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-soap.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-sockets.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-sqlite3.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-sysvmsg.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-sysvsem.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-sysvshm.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-tidy.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-tokenizer.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-xml.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-xmlwriter.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-xsl.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-zip.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/30-mysqli.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/30-pdo_mysql.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/30-pdo_odbc.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/30-pdo_sqlite.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/30-wddx.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/30-xmlreader.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/30-xmlrpc.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/memcache.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/memcached.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/zzzzzzz-pecl.ini

[usesrs@CentOS etc]$
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the contents of

```
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/memcache.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/memcached.ini,
```

and probably remove one of them - or put comments (the # sign) at the beginning of the lines.

Comment: Which should I want to remove? Will this remove process affect other running process?

Comment: If you do not want to remove one of these files - you can edit the chosen file and put `#` in column 1 on each line in the file. Then you have to restart the PHP daemon.

Comment: And this is a directory and both of above mentioned files are there. Then how to comment?

Comment: Like this `;extension=memcached`

Answer (score 0):

I got same error for redis which says

```
PHP Warning: Module 'redis' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

So in that case I found the redis.ini file on the location

```
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/redis.ini
```

Simply delete that `redis.ini` file

In your case you also find for same file & try to delete or hide that file.

Thank You!